# Compiling Audacity for ASIO support

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, asio, audacity

Using:

- Audacity 3.1.3 (Source clone from git)
- Python 3.9.6 (Env Variables setup correct)
- Conan 1.48.1
- CMake 3.23.2.0 (Using the cmake-gui application for this)
- Visual Studio Community 2019 v16.11.15 with "Desktop development with C++" installed

Following this link: https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/asio_audio_interface.html
, I've made it to step 6 at the very bottom "In CMake," on part 2, at the configure portion.
Following a good bit of things CMake does once i press the Configuration button, there is an error pop up near the end of this.

**Error in configuration process, project files may be invalid**

On further inspection I've noticed In the Log output that various things are **"Not found"**

And here Is the "full" log error message.

```
flac/1.3.3: WARN: Build folder is dirty, removing it: C:\Users\USER\.conan\data\flac\1.3.3\_\_\build\fc568baa27ee47f4752d1b052a39bc8b60761f3d

ERROR: 404: Not Found. [Remote: conancenter]
The 'flac/1.3.3' package has 'exports_sources' but sources not found in local cache.
Probably it was installed from a remote that is no longer available.
```

Inside of `CMakeError.log` I'm seeing all the **"Not Found"** variables output this - `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'm.lib'` etc.

And nothing in particular inside the `CMakeOutput.log`, appears as though the build worked without any warning/error from this files output.

Comment: FLAC is a separate package, you'll have to fix that first. Also, check for bug reports, maybe the issue is known. Further, is VS really a relevant part of your question? Can you trigger the issue without it? That would be one step towards the required (!) [mcve], but extracting all the rest from the audacity sources would be required as well. I think you really want a bug ticket rather. ;) That said, as a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: FLAC is required beforehand but not mentioned in the link i followed along with? Huh ok.

Comment: Please file a bug if the documentation is faulty, too! Open source lives from participation.